# Typescript - using exact type for returned data in React hook based on arg type

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, types, typescript-generics

I have a react hook that looks something like this:

```
export const useForm = <T>(values: T) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormFieldData<T>>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fields = {};
    for (const key in values) {
      const value = values[key];
      fields[key] = {
        value,
        errorMsg: '',
      };
    }
    setFormData(fields);
  }, []);

  return {
    formData,
  };
};
```

It accepts an object containing some fields and their default values, e.g:

```
  const { formData } = useForm({
    stringField: '',
    numberField: 1,
    booleanField: false,
  });
```

It takes these keys and default values, and uses them to build and return an object, `formData`:

```
{
  stringField: {
    value: '',
    errorMsg: '',
  },
  numberField: {
    value: 1,
    errorMsg: '',
  },
  booleanField: {
    value: false,
    errorMsg: '',
  },
}
```

In order for `formData` to be correctly typed, I am using a type `FormFieldData`, which accepts the generic type parameter passed to the hook, and uses these keys and values to create a type for `formData`:

```
export type FormField<T> = {
  errorMsg: string;
  value: T;
};

export type FormFieldData<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormField<T[keyof T]>;
};
```

The problem is, the type of each value in the field object in `formData` is a union type of all the different types passed to the hook. So using the above example, `formData.stringField.value` has a type of `string | number | boolean`.

I would expect the type of each fields `value` property to be the *same* type as the original value for that field that is passed into the hook, so `formData.stringField.value` to be `string` and `formData.numberField.value` to be `number`.

What am I missing here?

How come `T[keyof T]` creates a union of all the types in the generic object?

**Update**

I fixed this by changing the FormFieldData type to:

```
export type FormFieldData<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormField<T[K]>;
};
```

Comment: If you know the solution, i.e. since you have "I fixed this ...", please remove that content from the question and add it below as a self-answer to properly close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the FormFieldData type to:

```
export type FormFieldData<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormField<T[K]>;
};
```